# поиск слов цельных слов

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Не понимаю, почему захватило abea? ведь по идеи должно находить только цельное слово

```
echo preg_replace('#(ab)+#', '!', 'ab abab abab abababab abea');
```

должно было вывести только ! ! ! ! abea

а выводит ! ! ! ! !ea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы найти целое слово, состоящее из `ab`, используйте границы слова `\b`:

```
echo preg_replace('#\b(?:ab)+\b#', '!', 'ab abab abab abababab abea');
                    ^^       ^^

// => ! ! ! ! abea
```

См. [PHP-демо](https://ideone.com/eKqTER)

**Подробности**

- `\b` - начальная граница слова (перед текущей позицией может быть начало строки или цифра/буква/знак подчёркивания)
- `(?:ab)+` - одно или более повторений последовательности букв `ab` (`(?:...)` — незахватывающая группа, используемая только для группирования символов/шаблонов)
- `\b` - конечная граница слова (после текущей позиции может быть конец строки или цифра/буква/знак подчёркивания)

Answer (score 1):

Используйте опережающую отрицательную проверку:

```
echo preg_replace('~(ab)+(?!ea)~', '!', 'ab abab abab abababab abea');
// Вывод : ! ! ! ! abea
```